# How can I connect to a non-default firestore database using Node (using multiple firestore databases)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have multiple firestore databases in my project.
The databases were created using the command line and I can see it in the Firestore Databases preview following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project

I am able to connect to the default database, but am having problems connecting to other named databases. I would like to be able to update/delete data in those other databases.

I am attempting to connect to the databases using the lastest firebase-admin sdk (11.10.1) which has support for multiple named databases (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node)

I would like to use the functions `getFirestore(databaseId)` or `getFirestore(app, databaseId)`
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore)
but am getting the following error when I try to save data:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was for database 'projects/testproject/databases/testdb' but was attempting to access database 'projects/testproject/databases/(default)'

My code looks like this:

```
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const {
  initializeApp,
  applicationDefault,
} = require('firebase-admin/app');

const app = initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
});

const db = getFirestore();
const otherFirestore = getFirestore('testdb');

const saveData = async (col, doc, data) => {
  await otherFirestore
    .collection(col)
    .doc(doc)
    .set(data, { merge: true });
};
```

If I use db instead of otherFirestore, the data is saved into my default database.
I have also tried doing a `const otherFirestore = getFirestore(app, 'testdb');` but end up with the same error.
I am expecting the data to be saved to my testdb database.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For me, it does work exactly as you describe
const db = getFirestore();
const otherFirestore = getFirestore('testdb');
The string defines the name of the other database and if no string is set, it uses the "(default)" database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! Looks like it was my package was not being updated correctly despite having `"firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",` in my package.json. Had to run the following then trying it again seems to have fixed it.

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save
```

Answer (score 3):

After checking the comments and ideas at this post, here is my full solution:

To create a second, third firestore database, access Google Cloud, open Cloud Shell, select the project, running

*“gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]”*

and then run the command

*"gcloud alpha firestore databases create --database=NAME - -location=LOCATION --type=firestore-native --delete-protection"*

Then navigate to the firestore session as shown in the image below

[image: print google cloud]

I created the following code that is working for me to use more than one firestore database.

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
// credencial export at https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/((YOUR_PROJECT_ID))/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk?hl=pt-br 
//and click the button to create a new pair of private key

const config = {
    credential: cert(serviceAccount)
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(config);
const dbProduction = getFirestore(firebaseApp) //with no parameter, using default database
const dbDevelop = getFirestore(firebaseApp, "develop-database") //with name database as second parameter
const dbHomolog = getFirestore(firebaseApp, "homologation-database") //with name database as second parameter

//fast use to teste
dbProduction.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
dbDevelop.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
dbHomolog.collection("NAME_COLLECTION").add({test: true}) //.then()...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using multiple databases for the first time and it seems to be working with no errors. The only difference I see from your code is that I call initializeApp with no parameters. I'm also importing initializeApp and getFirestore differently (`import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'` instead of `const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');`) - that shouldn't make a difference, but maybe try that.

Comment: I sadly cannot easily swap over form using require to import, though I don't think it should make a difference either. I have tried calling initializeApp with no params, but got the same error. I'm assuming you are just doing a `gcloud auth application-default login` to access the firebase dbs? Were there any other configs or params you needed to add somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to do the following:

1. Updating all related depencencies versions to latest
2. Deleting node modules
3. Deleting `package-lock.json`
4. Running

```bash
npm i
```