# How can I connect to a non-default firestore database using Go?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I saw there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061688/how-can-i-connect-to-a-non-default-firestore-database-using-node-using-multiple) about connecting to a non-default firestore database using node. I am wondering if anyone is aware of the same feature in the firestore Go package?

I have tried a direct translation, but that did not work. Maybe the package isnt updated with this feature yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [NewClientWithDatabase](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#NewClientWithDatabase) to connect to a specific database.

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := firestore.NewClientWithDatabase(ctx, projectID, databaseID)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
defer client.Close() // Close client when done.
```