# Using a non-default Firestore database in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a single Firestore app with two databases. I want to add data to the collections that's in the second non-default database.

I already tried `await FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app(FIREBASE_DATABASE_NAME))` in place of `await FirebaseFirestore.instance` but it just gave me `FIREBASE_DATABASE_NAME` does not exist.

I read that there's a "databaseURL" parameter that I need to use, but I'm not sure where (and what) to put there.

[There's an answer for this using Node.js, but I need the equivalent for Flutter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061688/how-can-i-connect-to-a-non-default-firestore-database-using-node-using-multiple)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the [`FirebaseFirestore` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/instanceFor.html) says:

> You can get an instance by calling `FirebaseFirestore.instance`. The instance can also be created with a secondary Firebase app by calling `FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor`...

The signature of that method is:

```
FirebaseFirestore instanceFor(
  {required FirebaseApp app,
  String? databaseURL}
)
```

So you can get a non-default database with:

```
final db = FirebaseFirstore.instanceFor(app, "your non-default database name");
```

With:

- `app` being the value you get back when you call `Firebase.initializeApp`
- `"your non-default database name"` being the name that you gave your database (so not the URL, despite what the reference docs say)

Comment: oh okay, so basically I need to replace `FirebaseFirestore.instance` with  `await FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: FirebaseFirestore.instance.app, databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_NAME)`?