How to use Firebase named database with admin SDK
I've got two Firestore databases: the default database (default) and a named database test-db.
I am using the firebase-admin npm package to access these databases on my Node server.
By default Firestore uses the (default) database.
How do I get it to use a named database?
Both databases exist within Firestore and have the same permissions.
Here is my code, which happily connects to the (default) DB but I want it to connect to test-db:
import admin from 'firebase-admin'

process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path.join(__dirname, 'service-account-key.json')

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: 'https://test-db.firebaseio.com',
  databaseId: 'test-db'
})

const fs = admin.firestore(app)
console.log(fs.databaseId) // outputs (default)


I'm actually not sure what the syntax is for the legacy/namespaced API syntax (or if there even is one), but for the modular API it you can pass the database ID as the second argument to getFirestore(...). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061688/how-can-i-connect-to-a-non-default-firestore-database-using-node-using-multiple

@FrankvanPuffelen thank you, thank you, thank you, please add your comment as an answer and I will accept

Everything in the repo seems to point to it just being in the modular API: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Ffirebase-admin-node+firestore%28&type=code

Oh, if that solved it then this is a duplicate. I am a bit surprised at finding no mention of the legacy/namespaced API anywhere anymore though.

I didn't know const fs = admin.firestore(app) was legacy code! I've switched to using const fs = getFirestore(app, 'test-db') and everything works beautifully

Good to hear, @danday74!
