How to interact with a non-(default) database using firebase-admin
I currently have an application where I interface with the Firestore database through firebase-admin, for example:
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get();
if (snapshot.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});

I have now created a second database using the recent Firestore Multiple Databases feature. However, it's unclear to me how to select a specific database using firebase-admin.
There's an example on the google blog like this:
// Initialize Firebase App
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();

// Initialize Firestore Database with database id `test`
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app, “test”)

// Document Reference 
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(“col”).document(“doc”);

// Write Document
waitFor(docRef.set(Collections.singletonMap(“foo”, “bar”)));

However, that assumes the use of a firebase-firestore dependency, which we so far never needed.
Ideally, I'd want to switch between databases, since I might require data from both databases. Also, note that I use an emulator locally and deploy to several remote instances, so hardcoding a database URL in admin.initializeApp doesn't seem like an option.
Is this possible with firebase-admin?

Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061688/how-can-i-connect-to-a-non-default-firestore-database-using-node-using-multiple?

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, that seems to be a solution! I'll close this as a duplicate.
